# Nginx 1.18.0. ModSecurity WAF installation ./configure error

Tags: nginx

I am trying to install modsecurity in nginx 1.18.0 in ubuntu jammy 22.04.1 for a project by following hackersploit's tutorial:

https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/securing-nginx-with-modsecurity/

When building the modsecurity module for nginx using the `./configure` along with the configure arguments while in the `/opt/nginx-1.18.0` directory

```
sudo ./configure --add-dynamic-module=../ModSecurity-nginx --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/nginx-d8gVax/nginx-1.18.0=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-compat --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-d8gVax/nginx-1.18.0/debian/modules/http-geoip2 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_sub_module
```

It spits out this error at the end:

```
checking for OS
 + Linux 5.15.0-53-generic x86_64
checking for C compiler ... found
 + using GNU C compiler
 + gcc version: 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 
checking for gcc -pipe switch ... found
checking for --with-ld-opt="-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC" ... found
checking for -Wl,-E switch ... found
checking for gcc builtin atomic operations ... found
checking for C99 variadic macros ... found
checking for gcc variadic macros ... found
checking for gcc builtin 64 bit byteswap ... found
checking for unistd.h ... found
checking for inttypes.h ... found
checking for limits.h ... found
checking for sys/filio.h ... not found
checking for sys/param.h ... found
checking for sys/mount.h ... found
checking for sys/statvfs.h ... found
checking for crypt.h ... found
checking for Linux specific features
checking for epoll ... found
checking for EPOLLRDHUP ... found
checking for EPOLLEXCLUSIVE ... found
checking for O_PATH ... found
checking for sendfile() ... found
checking for sendfile64() ... found
checking for sys/prctl.h ... found
checking for prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE) ... found
checking for prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS) ... found
checking for capabilities ... found
checking for crypt_r() ... found
checking for sys/vfs.h ... found
checking for nobody group ... not found
checking for nogroup group ... found
checking for poll() ... found
checking for /dev/poll ... not found
checking for kqueue ... not found
checking for crypt() ... not found
checking for crypt() in libcrypt ... found
checking for F_READAHEAD ... not found
checking for posix_fadvise() ... found
checking for O_DIRECT ... found
checking for F_NOCACHE ... not found
checking for directio() ... not found
checking for statfs() ... found
checking for statvfs() ... found
checking for dlopen() ... found
checking for sched_yield() ... found
checking for sched_setaffinity() ... found
checking for SO_SETFIB ... not found
checking for SO_REUSEPORT ... found
checking for SO_ACCEPTFILTER ... not found
checking for SO_BINDANY ... not found
checking for IP_TRANSPARENT ... found
checking for IP_BINDANY ... not found
checking for IP_BIND_ADDRESS_NO_PORT ... found
checking for IP_RECVDSTADDR ... not found
checking for IP_SENDSRCADDR ... not found
checking for IP_PKTINFO ... found
checking for IPV6_RECVPKTINFO ... found
checking for TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT ... found
checking for TCP_KEEPIDLE ... found
checking for TCP_FASTOPEN ... found
checking for TCP_INFO ... found
checking for accept4() ... found
checking for eventfd() ... found
checking for int size ... 4 bytes
checking for long size ... 8 bytes
checking for long long size ... 8 bytes
checking for void * size ... 8 bytes
checking for uint32_t ... found
checking for uint64_t ... found
checking for sig_atomic_t ... found
checking for sig_atomic_t size ... 4 bytes
checking for socklen_t ... found
checking for in_addr_t ... found
checking for in_port_t ... found
checking for rlim_t ... found
checking for uintptr_t ... uintptr_t found
checking for system byte ordering ... little endian
checking for size_t size ... 8 bytes
checking for off_t size ... 8 bytes
checking for time_t size ... 8 bytes
checking for AF_INET6 ... found
checking for setproctitle() ... not found
checking for pread() ... found
checking for pwrite() ... found
checking for pwritev() ... found
checking for sys_nerr ... not found
checking for _sys_nerr ... not found
checking for maximum errno ... found
checking for localtime_r() ... found
checking for clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) ... found
checking for posix_memalign() ... found
checking for memalign() ... found
checking for mmap(MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED) ... found
checking for mmap("/dev/zero", MAP_SHARED) ... found
checking for System V shared memory ... found
checking for POSIX semaphores ... found
checking for struct msghdr.msg_control ... found
checking for ioctl(FIONBIO) ... found
checking for ioctl(FIONREAD) ... found
checking for struct tm.tm_gmtoff ... found
checking for struct dirent.d_namlen ... not found
checking for struct dirent.d_type ... found
checking for sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN) ... found
checking for sysconf(_SC_LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE) ... found
checking for openat(), fstatat() ... found
checking for getaddrinfo() ... found
configuring additional dynamic modules
adding module in ../ModSecurity-nginx
checking for ModSecurity library ... not found
checking for ModSecurity library in /usr/local/modsecurity ... found
 + ngx_http_modsecurity_module was configured
adding module in /build/nginx-d8gVax/nginx-1.18.0/debian/modules/http-geoip2
./configure: error: no /build/nginx-d8gVax/nginx-1.18.0/debian/modules/http-geoip2/config was found
```

I tried looking answers on google and hackersploit's comment section and I couldn't find any answers. I tried installing the geoip2 library using apt but I still end up getting this error. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: If you bold everything, you bold nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `libmodsecurity3` is missing from your system, may be you forgot this step:

https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/securing-nginx-with-modsecurity/#downloading--building-modsecurity

Btw: if you don't want to care the building of your WAF, you should take a look to this repository: https://modsecurity.digitalwave.hu

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to configure nginx-quic with ngtcp2 and nghttp2 on ubuntu 22 using below command(old command) but first i too faced the same error and after some debugging i found out that i using a config which will take using command nginx -V 2>&1 | sed "s/ --/ \\ \n\t--/g" | grep "--" | grep -ve opt= -e param= -e build= and it has the --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-d8gVax/nginx-1.18.0/debian/modules/http-geoip2 \

By using the new command you can exclude this --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-d8gVax/nginx-1.18.0/debian/modules/http-geoip2 \ from the config and nginx-quic will install sucessfully

Old command which gave me error

```
nginx/auto/configure nginx -V 2>&1 | sed "s/ \-\-/ \\\ \n\t--/g" | grep "\-\-" | grep -ve opt= -e param= -e build= --build=nginx-quic --with-debug  --with-http_v3_module --with-stream_quic_module --with-cc-opt="-I/src/boringssl/include" --with-ld-opt="-L/src/boringssl/build/ssl -L/src/boringssl/build/crypto"
```

New command which solved the issue

```
nginx/auto/configure nginx -V 2>&1 | sed "s/ \-\-/ \\\ \n\t--/g" | grep -v -e 'http-geoip2' | grep "\-\-" | grep -ve opt= -e param= -e build= --build=nginx-quic --with-debug  --with-http_v3_module --with-stream_quic_module --with-cc-opt="-I/src/boringssl/include" --with-ld-opt="-L/src/boringssl/build/ssl -L/src/boringssl/build/crypto"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yeah,okay,will edit

Answer (score 0):

simply download http-geoip2 module from here

[ngx_http_geoip2_module](https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module)

then then put the right path of the module you download in configure

```
sudo ./configure --add-dynamic-module=../ModSecurity-nginx --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/nginx-d8gVax/nginx-1.18.0=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-compat --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --add-dynamic-module=/path/http-geoip2 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_sub_module
```